# Employee Model definition without an ORM

Tags: javascript, node.js, mvc, ecmascript-8

I am the author of this code.  It's from an actual project, and it returns the desired result.  However, I am very concerned that I'm not defining my Model correctly.

The Model is instantiated in the Controller.  The Controller calls the instance of that Model.  The Model defines itself via `.map()`, then returns itself via `return this;`.

I believe I've created a situation that allows me to manipulate data returned from the Stored Procedure before it's returned to the Controller.

Do you agree?  Am I doing this right?  (I cannot use an ORM because I'm required to use Stored Procedures.  I'm trying to use as much ES6 as possible, like Classes and Map).

**Employee Controller**

```
const Employee = require('../models/Employee');
const employee = new Employee();

console.log(`I am the emoyeeController...  This is employee just after instantiation ===>`)
console.log(employee)

function getEmployeeById(req, res) {
    //req.params
    //req.params.id

    const { id } = req.params; // ES6 destructuring   

    employee.FindById(id).then(e =>{
        console.log(`Hi.  I'm the employee Controller... this is the employee after calling the model ===>`)
        console.log(e)
        res.json({e})
    });

}

module.exports = {
    getEmployeeById
};
```

**Employe Model**

```
const db = require('../config/db');

class Employee {

    constructor() {
        this.EEID = null;
        this.FullName = null;
        this.SSN = null;
    }

    async FindById(id) {
        try {
            const result = await db.raw("exec cbo.StoredProcedureName '', '', '', :id", { id })

            result.map(x => {
                this.EEID = x.id
                this.FullName = x.txtFullName
                this.SSN = x.txtSSN
            });

            return this;
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
        }
    }
}

module.exports = Employee;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Naming: variables, methods

Many popular style guides (e.g. [esLint](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/code-conventions#naming), [Google JS](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#naming-method-names), [AirBnB](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#naming--camelCase), etc.) recommend `camelCase` for method names - use `findById` instead of `FindById`. The same goes for variables.

Presuming `db.raw('EXEC cbo.StoredProcedureName')` always returns an array then `results` or `records` would be more appropriate than `result` since it would store an array that may contain multiple records.

### Main question

> #### Do you agree? Am I doing this right?

Let us look at how the properties are assigned- using `.map()`:

> ```
> result.map(x => {
>     this.EEID = x.id
>     this.FullName = x.txtFullName
>     this.SSN = x.txtSSN
> });
> ```

Let's also look at the [MDN documentation for `.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> ### Array.prototype.map()
>
> The **map()** method **creates a new array** populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.
>
> ...
>
> #### [When not to use map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#when_not_to_use_map)
>
> Since map builds a new array, using it when you aren't using the returned array is an anti-pattern; use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead.
>
> You shouldn't be using map if:
>
> - you're not using the array it returns; and/or
> - you're not returning a value from the callback.
>
> <sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)</sup>

As the documentation points out, you shouldn't be using `.map()` if you aren't using the return value. It could simply use `.forEach()` instead of `.map()` - in either case the values from the last set of values gets used to assign to properties of `this`.

A better solution would be to ensure that `result` has a length greater than zero and use the first result - there should only be one element if the `id` field is unique. For example, if there are no records returned it could [`throw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) an [`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) (or appropriate subclass), which could be caught by the controller to return a 404 status, though that may not be what is desired.

```
const result = await db.raw("exec cbo.StoredProcedureName '', '', '', :id", { id })
if (!result.length) {
    //handle case where record not found 
    throw new Error('record by id not found');
}
const record = result[0];
this.EEID = record.id;
this.FullName = record.txtFullName;
this.SSN = record.txtSSN;
```

The record could also be [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to only the fields needed:

```
const { txtFullName, txtSSN } = result[0];
```

And the assignment could also be achieved using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
Object.assign(this, { EEID: id, FullName: txtFullName, SSN: txtSSN });
```

As radarbob’s answer states: “*Requiring an employee object to fetch its own data doesn't make design sense*”. Instead of having an instance method `FindById` perhaps it would be better to make that be a [**static method**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Static_method) that will create a new instance after finding the record from the database. That way the constructor can accept the properties and they don’t have the be initialized to `NULL` before the real values are available.

See a demonstration below by expanding the snippet

```js
/* Fake database object */ 
const db = {
    raw: function(statement, { id }) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            resolve([{
                id,
                txtFullName: 'Luke Skywalker',
                SSN: 73
            }]);
        });
    }
};
class Employee {
    constructor(id, FullName, SSN) {
        this.EEID = id;
        this.FullName = FullName;
        this.SSN = SSN;
    }
    static async findById(id) {
        try {
            const result = await db.raw("exec cbo.StoredProcedureName '', '', '', :id", { id });
            const { txtFullName, txtSSN } = result[0];
            return new this(id, txtFullName, txtSSN);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
        }
    }
}
class EmployeeController {
    getEmployeeById(req, res) {

        const { id } = req.params; // ES6 destructuring   

        Employee.findById(id).then(e =>{
            console.log(`Hi.  I'm the employee Controller... this is the employee after calling the model ===>`);
            console.log(e);
            //res.json({e})
        });
    }
}
const ctrlr = new EmployeeController();
ctrlr.getEmployeeById({params: { id: 1337 }});
```

### Follow-up question

> Notice that I "remap" `txtSSN` to `SSN`, as specified in the `constructor`. Is that bad practice?

I don’t believe it is bad practice. It is common to have database column names that are different than what is desired for the API fields.

If you have control over the stored procedure and it has a `SELECT` query then the SQL query could be updated to have aliases on the columns in the `SELECT` clause - that might eliminate the need to map columns.

Comment: OMG!!  That `object.assign()` is the answer!!!  That's what I wanted - your explanations are really helpful.  Notice that I "remap" `txtSSN` to `SSN`, as specified in the `constructor`.  Is that bad practice?  Although I *could* immediately send back the DB response without "remapping" it, I wanted a way to manipulate data before returning it to the Controller.  Example: obscure the SSN, or add a Job Title to the end of the Full Name.

Comment: Cool. I amended my answer to contain a response to the question in your comment, and also updated the main suggestion to promote using a static method.

Comment: If I `return new this`, will I end up with a bunch of extra objects taking up memory somewhere?

Comment: Presuming that you accept the suggestion to use a static method, then it just shifts the instantiation - i.e. `new this` to inside that static method, so no it would not be extra objects, since the static call `Employee.findById` is on the class, not an individual instance - does that make sense?

Comment: I need to apply your recommendations to fully understand.  When I can properly describe it in English words, I will add a comment here.

Answer (score 7):

> I cannot use an ORM because I'm required to use Stored Procedures

Exchanging one for the other (and back again if you like) should not impact the Model design. So the right question is "... define a Model without regard to the database". A "business domain" object is not a database thing.

> I've created a situation that allows me to manipulate data returned from the Stored Procedure before it's returned to the Controller.

Not sure exactly the intent of "manipulate data" but the `Employee` constructor is the best place to validate arguments and instantiate a valid `Employee`.

Requiring an employee object to fetch its own data doesn't make design sense. That and strongly coupling the `Employee` model to the database - `Employee.FindById()` - are both antithetical to `Employee` single responsibility. This code, as is, makes it impractical to entertain the question of swapping out data-fetch-and-store mechanisms.

> The Model is instantiated in the Controller.

Technically yes, but it is not a valid `Employee` object. The `Employee` constructor should be passed the values to guarantee we create valid object. This means the data calls should be made from the Controller.

This is a constructor's true, special purpose. In other words constructor parameters tells you what is required for a valid object, will let you know if otherwise, and ideally, will not create an object with bad data.

---

**The Data Layer**

The Controller will have your desired methods, such as `FetchById()`. These methods will in turn call the appropriate data object's methods, like a corresponding `FetchById`.

In other words you will "declare" a common set of methods that every data object will implement. ***Now we can swap out ORM and stored procedure data objects***

Any data object that implements the required methods can be passed into the Controller.

Comment: Technically, I could leave out the `constructor`. The response from KNEX is proper JSON, so, I *could* just send that back to the controller directly.  My queries are all in Stored Procedures.  I'm using KNEX, which is more of a "query builder" and less of an "ORM".  So, I was trying to build my own Model since KNEX doesn't have one (like Sequelize).

Comment: Keeping MVC components decoupled means you can expect to write data-transmogrifying code to conform to your Model (or Controller or View) design. Sam Onela's answer is an example of how technical considerations can change data structures. Write transforming code to fit your Model, for example. That is far easier and far less error prone than rewriting broad swaths of core code that's already working.

Comment: *I could leave out the constructor*   You must still assign values to object properties. Using `constructor` well makes it obvious what a object instantiation requires. It's a huge START HERE sign. That does not change just because the incoming data is wrapped in a JSON object, a Set of individual values, an array of JSON objects, an array of a single JSON object .... Your post shows you realize going to ORM, or KNEX, whatever, is going to cause code changes everywhere. You need to isolate your Model from the whims of "the outside world."

Answer (score 2):

I've done a lot of sql + stored-proc over the years.

Some things to watch out for:

- data formats : Dates / Times (Timezone?), integers (7,123.01 v. 6.321,7 v. 5.600e-3 etc), sizes of numbers (and length of number-strings), etc.
- text encoding : Ascii (José ??), UTF-8, "windows quotes", Win1251, KOI8, GB18030, EBCDIC, etc etc
- security : your DB driver should be using a read-only connection, as a user with minimal necessary privs. A Read/Write-permitted connection can be used for inserts/updates/deletes.
- Unique IDs : the DB should be returning new IDs for new records
- results scrolling : a typical query giving a list of records may begin sending data as soon as it's ready on the server; other time (depending on indexing and sorting) it will wait until the full result set is ready before sending. On your (client) side, it's important to think through the implications of choices; - * waiting for last record available; * reading the full dataset into memory before processing; * processing each record as it arrives. The db resultset will typically be a forward-only iterator.

Comment: My hope is that I can control access to the backend through passport.js and authorization tokens, or something like that.  Right now, the "API account" is only granted EXECUTE on the Stored Proc; this account has no other CRUD permissions.  I'd eventually like to use an ORM one day, but I would need to grant SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, etc etc etc, and the Boss Man is a little reluctant on that, unless I can guarantee security.

Comment: the boss may be wise ;) .. Orms can be fun, or a complete nightmare .. Stored-procs provide very good isolation, and can make testing very easy. I personally prefer it that way, as (mostly-jokingly) i never met an Orm i didn't end up fighting with ;)